Implementation of Hikori's MSLC APSP algo
I would like to create a Rust implementation of the algorithm in this research paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hiroki-Yanagisawa-2/publication/224140603_A_multi-source_label-correcting_algorithm_for_the_all-pairs_shortest_paths_problem/links/0046352a1270f06e2e000000/A-multi-source-label-correcting-algorithm-for-the-all-pairs-shortest-paths-problem.pdf
The research paper lays out the following pseudo-code, in Algorithm 3.3:
Input: A graph G = (V, E) and a set of source vertices S
1: d(s, v) = ∞ and s(v) = unreached for every vertex v ∈ V and s ∈ S
2: d(s, s) = 0, s(s) = labeled, k(s) = 0, add s to priority queue Q for every s ∈ S
3: while Q is not empty do
4:   Remove a vertex v with the minimum key k(v) from Q
5:   for each edge (v, w) ∈ E outgoing from v do
6:     updated = false
7:     for all s ∈ S do
8:       if d(s, w) > d(s, v) + `(v, w) then
9:         d(s, w) = d(s, v) + `(v, w), s(w) = scanned, and updated = true
10:      end if
11:    end for
12:    if updated = true then
13:      Compute k(w) // e.g. set k(w) = min{d(s, w) | s ∈ S}
14:      Add w to Q if Q does not contain w
15:    end if
16:   end for
17: end while
18: Output d(s, v) for all s ∈ S and v ∈ V

I'm puzzled that it seems s(v) is only ever written to, but never read/used. Can anyone clue me in to what its purpose is?

And nothing in the research paper gives you any clue?

@JimMischel I've read it carefully and don't see anything that describes the use of s(v). Perhaps it is computed just as information for the user when the algo finishes. I'll implement the algo as-is and see if it works.
